# AWS: Cannot encrypt an S3 object using my own KMS key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

Created a key in KMS, allowed myself to use this key to encrypt. Uploaded an object into S3. Tried to encrypt this object using this new key. Got the following error:

[image]

Comment: Is there any other debugging information available? CloudTrail may show some more information for you

Comment: No CloudTrail didn't show any record. I think the root problem is: my key didn't show up on the drop down box when I selected the "AWS KMS" radio button. Why isn't my key shown? The key I created was given region of us-east-1, while my S3 bucket was in Sydney. Was it the reason? But I have no choice of the key's region.

Comment: The key I created was given region of us-east-1, while my S3 bucket was in Sydney. I just created a s3 bucket in us-east-1, and I could encrypt the s3 object with the key I created. But how do I create a key for my own region? There isn't a choice of region when I created the keys, and they are automatically given region us-east-1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked out how to pick region. Before you click the "create key" button, select the region below that button. Totally inconsistent UI design.